# Hbase standalone rootdir relative path

Tags: hbase

I downloaded hbase 1.2.2 and try to run it on my macbook at stand alone mode, when i execute the start-hbase.sh it works pretty well. But now i'am trying to set the rootdir to store my data permanent. Is there a way to use a relative path to set the rootdir of hbase? i tried this in the hbase-site.xml but this does not work :(

```
<configuration>

<property>

<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>file:///./Data/hbase</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>./Data/zookeeper</value>

</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
<value>file:///./Data/hbase</value>
```

**To**

```
<value>./Data/hbase</value>
```